# Photodiode pulse detect system

Tags: comparator, photodiode, pulse

We have a laser signal detection system as shown in the figure below. In this system, we want to detect the incoming laser pulse. The MCU will detect the incoming pulse and perform its operations accordingly. That is, the pulse signal is either present or not. I will not take any operation with the time of flight.

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 1. Detect System**

[image]

**Figure 2. Pulse**

The pulse signal is 10ns and ranges from 50-100MHz. An example pulse signal is seen in Figure 2.

1. I want to detect the incoming pulse signal only with the comparator and read it with the MCU. It's a high frequency signal and I think high MCU speeds would be needed to detect it. Am I wrong? Can I miss pulse signals when I do it this way? Does it work to use latch so I don't miss it?
2. When I do it with a [TDC7201](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc7201.pdf), can I read every incoming pulse signal from the interrupt registers?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention a few of the requirements, such as the resolution required to read the laser pulse ? So that you give an example of a 10ns pulse, how many ppm resolution will suffice for this pulse reading, 10, 100, 1000 ppm ? This will better define your requirements....

Comment: Once you define the minimum resolution required, then you can get a very accurate pulse generator and replace the TDC7201 and comparator, and generate the required 10ns (with say, ±1000ppm) pulses with the required resolution and see what the micro can detect with the recommended clock etc. Don't forget that the micro clock crystal ppm will also add uncertainty in those measurements, so keep the crystal ppm as low as possible ...

Comment: does resolution matter here? I will not generate any signals. I just want to read whether the output is 1 or 0. And I'm thinking of reading the comparator output, using the timer unit for that. The speed of the timer is important here? Because the comparator output will be digital 1 for a very short time.

Comment: ahhh, you're not reading a time delay ? my apologies ... In that case replace the TransAmp and the photo-receiver by the pulse generator and set the pulses analogous to your expected pules from the optical system, and observe the results (with and without the TDC7201 if you have time) ... If you are actually reading pulse widths with a certain minimum resolution, then see my above comments after all ...

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I will consider your suggestions.

Comment: Microcontrollers likely latch logic input signals using their own clock. Even if it can detect such a narrow pulse, pulse presence would be **aliased** by this re-clocking. You may have to phase-lock the microcontroller crystal clock with the clock that generates the laser pulse.